# value error while converting object to int

Tags: python, pandas

my quantity dtype is object (from csv file) and I am trying to covert to int using below code:

```
df[x1] = df[x1].astype(str).astype(int)
```

It throws error as below:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,000.000'
```

Can anyone help me in this please?

Comment: Please share a sample input dataframe with expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `','` and `'.'`. You can use `str.replace` method to remove the comma and then cast the data to type float then to type int.

```
df[x1] = df[x1].str.replace(',','').astype(float).astype(int)
```

For example, for a Series such as

```
srs = pd.Series(['1,000.00','1'])
```

if you cast it to dtype `int`

```
srs.astype(int)
```

you get

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,000.00'
```

Then if you remove the comma `str.replace` method and cast to dtype `int`

```
srs = srs.str.replace(',','')
srs.astype(int)
```

you get

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1000.00'
```

So you cast it to dtype float and to dtype int,

```
srs = srs.str.replace(',','').astype(float).astype(int)
```

you get the expected outcome:

```
0    1000
1       1
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda functions!

```
df[x1] = df[x1].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually int() function expects an integer string or a float, but not a float string. If a float string is given you need to convert it to float first then to int as:

```
int(float(userGuess))
```

So you have to convert it to float first and then to int.